# How to interpret gradient and parameter histograms in tensorboardX?

Tags: python, deep-learning, statistics, pytorch, tensorboard

I ran AlexNet on an ImageNet database for 3 epochs and got this while plotting grads/params. -

```
Params in epoch 2
```

[image: Epoch 2 params]

```
Epoch 2 params distribution
```

[image]

```
Grads in epoch 2
```

[image]

```
Epoch 2 grads distribution
```

[image]

```
Parameters over epochs
```

[image]

```
Distribution of params over epochs
```

[image]

```py
# Code for Epoch wise plot
# Add this to the training loop in the train_one_epoch function
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
           writer.add_histogram(
               tag=f"epoch_{epoch}_params/{name}", values=param, global_step=batch
           )
           writer.add_histogram(
               tag=f"epoch_{epoch}_grads/{name}", values=param.grad, global_step=batch
           )
# For run parameters - 
# Add this to end of epoch loop
for layer, (name, param) in enumerate(model.named_parameters()):
         writer.add_histogram(
             tag=f"run_params/{name}", values=param, global_step=epoch
         )
```

**I have the following questions in mind -**

1. What do these graphs mean and how to read them?
2. Can we extrapolate if model has learnt anything using these graphs in say, epoch2 or over the whole run?. If so how?
3. Can we debug vanishing/exploding gradients using these graphs? (It would be awesome if you can share some examples of this.)
4. Finally, is breaking my head over this even useful?

Thanks in advance!